# POST value XML contains &quot; the PHP is truncating

Tags: php

I have a POST METHOD

```
$ab = $_POST['xml'];
```

xml data is the following:

```
<email CommunicationType="Email" SourceSystem="GPS" TemplatePageZone="" brand="THORN" channel="THORN" emailAddr="mallu@THORN.com" template="tttt_09999_TEST">
  <communicationTypes>
    <communicationType Name="EMAIL" Value="PETERS@THORN.com" isRequired="Y" />
    <communicationType MobileTemplateID="12345" Name="COMM" OptInUrl="OptInUrl" Value="1234567890" isPartialOrFull="" isRequired="Y" template="88888" />
  </communicationTypes>
  <name firstName="**SMITH&quot;** SON" lastName="" middleInitial="" />
  <order orderDate="05/16/2013" orderHeaderKey="287346JSDV" orderIdATG="THORN01-23423415" orderNoEOMS="THORN01-22324323015" >
    <creditCard card="" numbersss="" />
    <digitalCoupons digitalCouponTotal="0.00" />
    <lineItems />
  </order>
  <account atgProfileId="" cirisID="" info="" password="" />
  <comments />
</email>
```

```php
$xmlmain = simplexml_load_string($ab);
```

The issue is the $xmlmain cannot load the `$ab`, because of the special character `SMITH&quot;`

Everthing after SMITH gets truncated. I sent the EMAIL with variable `$xmlmain` to myself and I see everything after is truncated. And this leads to the following failure as well since the XML is not read.

```
$template_XMLMAIN =  $xmlmain->attributes()->template;  //This should be tttt_09999_TEST
```

Why I cannot read the XML? Thank You.

PS: This is the way the XML is going to be sent to me, cannot change it from the client side to me.

Comment: I have no problem with loading that XML, are you sure you are not decoding html entities by accident? Or are they sending an unencoded `&` in the POST body? (You could parse `php://input` manually in that case).

Comment: I tried this $rawdata = file_get_contents('php://input'); and everything after where the special character is gets TRUNCATED .

Comment: Do you mean the data is not even in `php://input`?

Comment: That's correct data is NOT even in php://input. For example: <email CommunicationType="Ema&quot;il" SourceSystem="GPS"

Comment: <email CommunicationType="Ema&quot;il" SourceSystem="GPS"...Everything after Ema is TRUNCATED, I don't get the rest of the XML information

Comment: If it's not in the raw `php://input`, it's not there. It more likely ges truncated on the other side, not on your server. Fix the unencoded `&` there (and please don't use capitals, it reads like SCREAMING).

Answer (score 0):

" is en entity which needs to be encoded with &quot; first.

The encoding needs to be done where the XML stream is created so that the string is like:

```
<name firstName="**SMITH&amp;quot;** SON" lastName="" middleInitial="" />
```

...

alternatively:

```
$ab = preg_replac('/&/', '&amp;', $ab);
$xmlmain = simplexml_load_string($ab);
```